# DirectX is difficult sometimes

Tags: directx11

I recently started DirectX 11. Sometimes I can't get my head around it.

1. First of all what are COM objects and why we do have to release them?
2. I have done most of initialization, but I am stuck in the rendering pipeline. How is a game structured? I mean you do the initialization (device, swapchain, viewpoint etc, back buffer etc.), you do the rendering pipeline and then what, do you have a framework, a very basic engine, you are done with low level stuff and continue programming graphics now?
3. How much do I have to learn directX, is it really that difficult?

Comment: COM is a lot easier to use in C++ if you make use of a smart pointer like ``Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr`` which takes care of the reference counts and calling ``Release`` automatically. See [this page](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) for details. COM is just a way to handle side-by-side versioning over time, and Direct3D isn't actually fully compliant with true COM in terms of lifetimes and factory creation. It just uses ``IUnknown`` for reference counting and the ability to query interfaces.

Comment: As you are new to DirectX, take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) for Direct3D 11 and it's [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started). Using the toolkit makes it a lot easier to get started, and it is open source so you can learn how each part works as you master different aspects. In particular, it covers device initialization, Windows desktop swapchain, and the basic game loop using a [simple project template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/01/06/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

1. COM objects are objects that forward their calls to another environment. How it works exactly is not important, what is important is that the underlying resources are reference counted; you increment the refcount with `acquire` and reduce it with `release`. when you create a COM object it is automatically initialized with a refcount of 1 so a single release with destroy it again.

   If you fail to release one it will leak and may cause issues for your system.
2. After initialization you would start the game loop. This is typically a while loop that checks the input, updates the game engine and renders the game to the screen.
3. I'm not going to get into this part as it's off-topic here. But I'll say it's easier if you use a game engine to build your game with as it would have most of the rendering and physics already implemented.